# Pandas' merge returns a column with _x appended to the name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have to dataframes, `df1` has columns *A, B, C, D...* and `df2` has columns *A, B, E, F...*

The keys I want to merge with are in column `A`. `B` is also (most likely) the same in both dataframes. This is a big dataset so I do not have a good overview of everything yet.

When I do

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A')
```

the results contains a column called `B_x`. Since the dataset is big and messy I haven't tried to investigate how `B_x` differs from `B` in `df1` and `B` in `df2`.

So my question is just in general: What does Pandas mean when it has appended `_x` to a column name in the merged dataframe?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The suffixes are added for any clashes in column names that are not involved in the merge operation, see [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

So in your case if you think that they are same you could just do the merge on both columns:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'])
```

What this will do though is return only the values where `A` and `B` exist in both dataframes as the default merge type is an `inner` merge.

So what you could do is compare this merged df size with your first one and see if they are the same and if so you could do a merge on both columns or just drop/rename the `_x`/`_y` suffix `B` columns.

I would spend time though determining if these values are indeed the same and exist in both dataframes, in which case you may wish to perform an `outer` merge:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'], how='outer')
```

Then what you could do is then drop duplicate rows (and possibly any `NaN` rows) and that should give you a clean merged dataframe.

```
merged_df.drop_duplicates(cols=['A', 'B'],inplace=True)
```

See online docs for [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates)

Answer (score 3):

A merged dataframe shouldn't have overlapping column names, so as EdChum mentioned, if the merged dataframe has `B_x` when it should have `B`, then it means both dataframes had column `B` and pandas made the executive decision to add suffixes `_x` to the `B` column of the left dataframe and `_y` to the `B` column of the right dataframe.

In fact, you can change what these suffixes should be by passing a tuple to `suffixes=` parameter of `merge()`. For example,

```py
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='A', suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

Now, `merged_df` will have `B_left` instead of `B_x`. If you pass empty strings:

```py
df1.merge(df2, on='A', suffixes=('', ''))
```

you'll get a ValueError similar to the following

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

which says that overlapping columns were identified.